# Redirigir en PHP

Tags: php, html, web

tengo un **formulario en PHP**, y quiero que al pulsar un botón "Aceptar", aparezca un alert, y al pulsar "Aceptar" en ese alert, me **redirija** a la página de inicio.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user (nombre, enamil) VALUES ('$name', '$email')";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

if ($result == False) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    die();
    echo "<script>alert('Error al insertar registro')</script>";
} else {
    header("Location: index.php");
    die();
    echo "<script>alert('Contraseña registrada');</script>";
}
```

He visto que también se puede redirigir mediante **js**, pero sigo sin obtener el resultado que quiero. También he probado a poner el alert antes de la redirección, pero tampoco funciona. ¿Alguien sabe como se puede hacer? Gracias.

Comment: Dos acciones para una redirección significa una pésima experiencia de usuario. ¿Por qué no simplificas tu código y le facilitas las cosas al usuario? En cuanto a tu código, no debes poner nada después de `header`, sólo  `exit();`, nada más. En este caso, lo mejor sería redirigir dese Javascript, pero como te digo, deberías repensar quizá las cosas, creando un programa más amigable, usando Ajax por ejemplo, o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript, que te permite comunicar entre cliente y servidor de forma fácil y transparente, sin tantas ventanas saltando, como el famoso `alert`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte, la verdad que no había pensado en la experiencia de usuario, lo tendré en cuenta.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer la redirección en el mismo javascript:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if( $result === false )
    $mensaje = 'Error al insertar registro';
else
    $mensaje = 'Contraseña registrada';

echo "<script>alert('$mensaje'); window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
```